# Target URI doesn't exist, when trying to import a package in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have stumbled upon a problem in importing the package in Flutter, I tried to solve this by running flutter packages get and also shutting down the project in Android studio and reopening it.

```
import 'package:task_02_category_widget/category.dart';
```

Here is the line above, and the error I'm running into when I run it gives the following error in the console.

```
Your application could not be compiled, because its dependencies could 
not be established.
The following Dart file:
  /Users/username/Documents/flutter_rectangle_2/lib/main.dart
...refers, in an import, to the following library:
package:task_02_category_widget/category.dart
That library is in a package that is not known. Maybe you forgot to 
mention it in your pubspec.yaml file?
```

Answer (score 0):

If task_02_category_widget/category.dart is part of an old project you are reusing you should put it in a folder in your flutter application and include it like "../ folder /task_02_category_widget/category.dart ". If it is part of github repository you have copy pasted from, just copy the file and use the step above. Most probably you are looking for [that](https://github.com/flutter/udacity-course/blob/master/course/02_category_widget/task_02_category_widget/lib/category) . In any other case check [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter) to find the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You should have in your project at a file called `pubspec.yaml` a definition like this:

```
name: my_app
dependencies:
  task_02_category_widget:
```

Let’s say that your package is laid out as follows:

```
task_02_category_widget/
  lib/
    category.dart
```

Then, you can import it:

```
import 'package:task_02_category_widget/category.dart';
```

**More information:**

https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/get-started

https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/create-library-packages